# How to Webscrape data from a classic asp website using python. I am having trouble getting the result after submitting the POST form

Tags: python, html, forms, web, web-scraping

I am beginner in Web scraping and I have become very much interested in the process.
I set for myself a Project that can keep me motivated till I completed the project.

## My Project

My Aim is to write a Python Program that goes to my university results page(which happens to be a " xx.asp") and enters my

1. MY EXAM NO
2. MY COURSE
3. SEMESTER and submit it to the website.

Clicking on the submit button leads to another "yy.asp" page in which my results are displayed. But I am having a lot of trouble doing the same.

### Some Sample Data to try it out

**The Results Website:** http://result.pondiuni.edu.in/candidate.asp

**Register Number:** 15te1218

**Degree:** BTHEE

**Exam:** Second

Could anyone give me directions of how I am to accomplish the task?

I have written a sample program that I am not really proud of or nor does it work as I wanted. The following is the code that I wrote. I am a beginner so sorry if I did something terribly wrong. Please correct me and would be awesome if you could guide me to solve the problem.

The website is a .asp website not .aspx.
I have provided sample data so that you can see whats happening where we submit a request to the website.

### The Code

```
import requests

with requests.Session() as c:
    url='http://result.pondiuni.edu.in/candidate.asp'
    url2='http://result.pondiuni.edu.in/ResultDisp.asp'
    TXTREGNO='15te1218'
    CMBDEGREE='BTHEE~\BTHEE\result.mdb'
    CMBEXAMNO='B'
    DPATH='\BTHEE\result.mdb'
    DNAME='BTHEE'
    TXTEXAMNO='B'
    c.get(url)

payload = {

    'txtregno':TXTREGNO,
    'cmbdegree':CMBDEGREE,
    'cmbexamno':CMBEXAMNO,
    'dpath':DPATH,
    'dname':DNAME,
    'txtexamno':TXTEXAMNO
}
post_request = requests.post(url, data=payload)
page=c.get(url2)
```

I have no idea what to do next so that I can retrieve my result page(displayed in `url2` from the code). All the data is entered in link `url` in the program(the starting link were all the info is entered) from where after submitting takes is to `url2` the results page.
Please help me make this program.

I took all the post form parameters from Chrome's Network Tab.

Comment: Have you explored what `post_request` contains? (it is actually a `Response` object)

Comment: I am sorry I have not. I tried to copy the code from another website and adapt it to my website. As said before.. The code is not proper. The problem is that I am finding it difficult to find website that do a tutorial on web scraping for .asp website(snearly all of them are for .aspx websites). Could you guide me how to write the proper code ?

Comment: @alecxe Got the code working after some help.I need all the data entered linearly in a spreadsheet with the sl.no,name,subject names of each subject on the top and the corresponding serial numbers,&data in its own columns.I am planning to do this in a loop for a set of students.There are clues in Tofuistofu's answer but I don't know how to organise them column wise, In such an arrangement, all the rows in the results page must be the columns of my csv file.Could you help me fill in just any 2 of the values ? I will follow what you have done and do the rest myself once I get the idea.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are way over complicating it and you have *carriage returns* in your post data so that could never work:

```
In [1]: s = "BTHEE~\BTHEE\result.mdb"

In [2]: print(s) # where did "\result.mdb" go?
esult.mdbHEE

In [3]: s = r"BTHEE~\BTHEE\result.mdb" # raw string

In [4]: print(s)
BTHEE~\BTHEE\result.mdb
```

So fix you form data and just post to get to your results:

```
import requests

data = {"txtregno": "15te1218",
        "cmbdegree": r"BTHEE~\BTHEE\result.mdb", # use raw strings
        "cmbexamno": "B",
        "dpath": r"\BTHEE\result.mdb",
        "dname": "BTHEE",
        "txtexamno": "B"}

results_page = requests.post("http://result.pondiuni.edu.in/ResultDisp.asp", data=data).content
```

Answer (score -1):

To add to the answer already given, you can use bs4.BeautifulSoup to find the data you need in the result page afterwards.

```
#!\usr\bin\env python

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

payload = {'txtregno': '15te1218',
    'cmbdegree': r'BTHEE~\BTHEE\result.mdb', 
    'cmbexamno': 'B',
    'dpath': r'\BTHEE\result.mdb',
    'dname': 'BTHEE',
    'txtexamno': 'B'}

results_page = requests.get('http://result.pondiuni.edu.in/ResultDisp.asp', data = payload)
soup = BeautifulSoup(results_page.text, 'html.parser')
SubjectElem = soup.select("td[width='66%'] font")
MarkElem = soup.select("font[color='DarkGreen'] b")

Subject = []
Mark = []
for i in range(len(SubjectElem)):
    Subject.append(SubjectElem[i].text)
    Mark.append(MarkElem[i].text)

Transcript = dict(zip(Subject, Mark))
```

This will give a dictionary with the subject as a key and mark as a value.

Comment: Hello Tofuistofu .. Thanks for helping me out buddy.. But I am not quite sure of how to get the output out of your code.. Could you tell me what i should print to get the subjects and the marks ?

Comment: I need all the data entered linearly in a spreadsheet with the sl.no,name,subject names of each subject on the top and the corresponding serial numbers, names, marks in each subject in its own column . Anyway to do that ?

Comment: Export the data as a csv file I suppose.. Can you guide to store data in the format i mentioned above in columns for each category as said in my previous comment ?